# React rest call map result to selectbox with avatar and label per option

Tags: reactjs, rest

Hi here is rest response:

```
[
  {
    "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/EX",
    "id": "10000",
    "key": "EX",
    "name": "Example",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10000",
      "24x24": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10000",
      "16x16": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10000",
      "32x32": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10000"
    },
    "projectCategory": {
      "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/projectCategory/10000",
      "id": "10000",
      "name": "FIRST",
      "description": "First Project Category"
    },
    "simplified": false,
    "style": "classic",
    "insight": {
      "totalIssueCount": 100,
      "lastIssueUpdateTime": "2022-12-08T07:09:19.702+0000"
    }
  },
  {
    "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/ABC",
    "id": "10001",
    "key": "ABC",
    "name": "Alphabetical",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10001",
      "24x24": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10001",
      "16x16": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10001",
      "32x32": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10001"
    },
    "projectCategory": {
      "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/projectCategory/10000",
      "id": "10000",
      "name": "FIRST",
      "description": "First Project Category"
    },
    "simplified": false,
    "style": "classic",
    "insight": {
      "totalIssueCount": 100,
      "lastIssueUpdateTime": "2022-12-08T07:09:19.702+0000"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to make select bobx having

```
<option value={data.id}><Img {data.16x16}/>data.label</option>
```

But result would be all projects if company has multiple projects so select box values have to map or loop into react

```
<Select options="result">
```

Im stuck as my code displays only label not any image there.
Another problem is that using `data.avatarUrls.16x16` does not compile. VSCode says expecting "," and puts red underline to 16x16

Here is my code a lot is broken here because I have tested a lot ways but no luck

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'

import { components } from 'react-select';

//Kun selectbox
const handleChange = event => {
  //console.log(event.target.value);
  setSelected(event.target.value);
};
//Palauttaa projectit json taulukon


const getProjects = async () => {
  //Matti tähän sitten atlasion cmpany projection haku
  const response = await api.asUser().requestJira(route`/rest/api/3/project`, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  //Mapataa hausta tarvittavat tiedot
  const result = data.map(function (item, i) {
    console.log('test');
    return [
      {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.id,
        avatar: item.avatarUrls.16x16
      }
    ]
  })
  return result
}

function Projects() {
  //haetaan atlasiansita projectit array
  const p = getProjects
  //asetetaan state selectbox muutokselle
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(p.id);

  return (
    <div className='projects'>
      <Select 
        className='select-projects' 
        options={p} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Projects
```

Comment: It should be `<option value={data.id}><img src = {data.16x16}/>data.label</option>`

Comment: I got it working in the end, needed Select prop -> formatLabel (options) => { adding own layout for selectbox here }

But now I have problem I need to make this into class havin update state functions as I need to hidden selectbox when I need and I think functional react cant have public funtions to modify behaviour. In a case when another select box commands another select to display options and so on.